# Retrieve Image from Database and display in another jsp page

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, servlets

I am trying to retrieve multiple images from database and display those images in another JSP page.
First, I tried single image to display in particular JSP page, I retrieved but the display is showing as file type,
I want to display that image in particular JSP page.
I am using MySQL database.

**my servlet code:**

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;


@WebServlet("/Retrieve")
public class Retrieve extends HttpServlet {
    static {
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException 
    {   Connection con = null;
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
ResultSet rs = null;

        try {
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/vikas", "root", "root");
            ps = con.prepareStatement("select * from rough");
            rs=ps.executeQuery();
                    if (rs.next()) {
                        byte[] content = rs.getBytes("image");
                        response.setContentLength(content.length);
                        response.getOutputStream().write(content);
                        request.setAttribute("image", content);
                        RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("View.jsp");  
                        rd.forward(request, response);  
                    } else {
                        response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_NOT_FOUND); // 404.
                    }

            } catch (SQLException e) {
                throw new ServletException("Something failed at SQL/DB level.", e);
            }
        }


    }
```

**jsp code:**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Display Image</title>
</head>
<body>
<div>THE DISPLAY</div>
<div style="width:25%; height:25%">
<%request.getAttribute("image"); %>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you post your jsp code here

Comment: Maybe you need to add content type. Something like: response.setContentType(getServletContext().getMimeType(imageName));

Comment: First of all if you want to make forward you should not write to output stream of the response or set content length. You may try to convert the bytes to Base64 image file string for example png or jpg and pass it to the attribute and then to src on img tag as the request scope attribute image. `<div style="width:25%; height:25%">
<img src="<%=request.getAttribute("image"); %>"/>
</div>`

Answer (score 2):

Try using `Base64` encoding,

Use [Apache Commons Codec](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/) to do Base64 encodings.

```
byte[] content = rs.getBytes("image");
String base64Encoded = new String(Base64.encodeBase64(content), "UTF-8");
request.setAttribute("imageBt", base64Encoded);
```

Retrieve it from JSP

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,${requestScope['imageBt']}"/>
```

For multiple images you could try something like this, (i didnt try this)

```
List<String> images = new ArrayList<>();
if (rs.next()) {
    byte[] content = rs.getBytes("image");
    images.add(new String(Base64.encodeBase64(content), "UTF-8"));
}
request.setAttribute("imageBt", images);
```

In JSP

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>

<c:forEach var="img" items="${imageBt}">
    <img src="data:image/png;base64, ${img}"/>
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: @ Benjamin C,   Yes I got it. Thank you. Will u please help in "how to retrieve multiple images from database."

Comment: @VIKASDUBBAKA multiple images means multiple byte arrays, you should retrieve them from database as usual and encode to base64 strings, now you have a list of strings, then set this list to request attribute and from jsp, iterate trough that list as `c:forEach`

Comment: sorry i don't have enough reputations to accept your answer

Comment: @VIKASDUBBAKA check the modified answer for multiple image case, but i did not try that code

Comment: that code is not working

Comment: @VIKASDUBBAKA which part ?

Comment: sorry sorry its working, but my requirement is the images should display one by one but im getting in one line

Comment: @VIKASDUBBAKA restructure your html, may be putting `<br>` at the end of `<img>`

Comment: Thank you, i got it